# using computed column name in window function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use a computed_field inside the window function

```
SELECT 
  DATE(activity_date) AS "activity_date",
  activity_app AS "activity_app",
  CASE
    WHEN join_date < 'X' THEN 'A' 
    WHEN join_date < 'Y' THEN 'B' 
    .......
    ELSE 'Unknown' 
  END AS "some_computed_field",
  COUNT(user_id) AS "count_users",
  AVG(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY activity_app,some_computed_field ORDER BY activity_date rows BETWEEN 2 preceding and current row) AS "special_average"
  FROM some_table
```

Throws :

`ERROR: column "some_computed_field" does not exist in some_table`

I can always write the complete `case` statement inside the window function but then I do not want to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like the window function can't see what the pseudo-column is referring to. I suppose from the planner point of view this entry isn't resolvable when it's computing how to access the subsets inside the window function.

I guess you have to look at restructuring the query so that the fake column is a real one somehow.

You could probably convert the case statement into a sql function `compute_field()`, and then use `compute_field(join_date)`, this would factor away the repetition.

```
CREATE FUNCTION compute_field (join_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) RETURNS TEXT as
$$
SELECT
 CASE
    WHEN join_date < now() THEN 'A' 
    WHEN join_date < now() - interval '1 year'  THEN 'B' 
    ELSE 'Unknown' 
END
$$ language 'SQL';


SELECT 
  DATE(activity_date) AS "activity_date",
  activity_app AS "activity_app",
  compute_field(join_date),
  COUNT(user_id) AS "count_users",
  AVG(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY activity_app,compute_field(join_date)  ORDER BY activity_date rows BETWEEN 2 preceding and current row) AS "special_average"
FROM some_table
GROUP BY some_table.activity_date, some_table.activity_app, compute_field(join_date) ;
```

If creating functions is a problem, and if you don't mind a double scan over the table, you could wrap the case in a CTE and then join it into the results, something like this

```
WITH computed AS ( SELECT CASE
                              WHEN join_date < now() THEN 'A'
                              WHEN join_date < now() + interval '12 days'  THEN 'B'
                              ELSE 'Unknown'
                          END as "field", 
                  join_date as "jd"
                  FROM some_table )
SELECT
      DATE(activity_date) AS "activity_date",
      activity_app AS "activity_app",
      COUNT(user_id) AS "count_users",
      AVG(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY activity_app,computed.field ORDER BY activity_date rows BETWEEN 2 preceding and current row) AS "special_average"
FROM some_table join computed on join_date = jd
GROUP BY some_table.activity_date, some_table.activity_app,computed.field
```

I've substituted some junk values into the SQL there, just to check it parses ( also added a GROUP for every non-aggregate for the same reason )

Comment: redshift doesn't support functions, so thats out. Looking into the next option